# How can I import module with same name as __main__ program in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-3.7

I study many answers on similar questions (opening same name modules that is trivial) but I not found answer to this question how to open module with same file name as `__main__` program.

Let see my code tree (it is simplified for this purpose):

```
<source root>
  log_parser/
    log_parser.py (module to import)
  my_system/ 
    log_parser/
      log_parser.py (__main__)
```

As you see on the tree I want to import `log_parser/log_parser`. `<source root>` is added to path.

Python adds to path current path as first. I found that I can exclude current path from import paths and this works. Is there and alternative solution more pythonic?

```
<other imports>

sys.path = sys.path[1:]

from log_parser.log_parser import LogParser
```

How to import without monkey like that `sys.path = sys.path[1:]` or `del sys.path[0]`?

I can rename modules but I do not want ugly and too long names like `my_system_log_parser.my_system_log_parser`.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: This seems like a naming issue more than a coding issue (as your edit suggests you've already considered), so I'll comment rather than answer. In python, self-documenting code means having descriptive naming conventions. If it were me, I would have the names reflect what the script is actually doing (`log_parser.LogParser` for the module, then `local_project` for the local script).

Comment: @tituszban Probably can be used but syntax in less readable that path patching.

Comment: @G.Anderson Code source/base will be very large so I can not use simple names convention by design. Consider that I will code 'abstract layer' than I wil code 2-3 'project/system layers' than I will code 2-3 tool per project. Abstract layer will bring generic functions, project layer will extend base class into many specific classes for each type of log for project that I will write some tool in project/system. You can assume that I will do universal log parser than more specific parsers and finally tools running parsers in parallel. For one system and simple log I will write  simpler code.

Comment: So structure is: abstract parser -> specific system -> many specific parsers -> specific system tools. I prefer log_parser.BaseLogParser -> sys_name.log_parser -> BaseFormat1Parser, BaseFormat2Parser -> Service1FormatParser,  Service2Format1Parser, Service3Format1Parser ... - this ugly names is only to show number of variations I will find better names. That is why I want have two modules with log_parser, project_name.log_parser names. Not log_parser and project_name_log_parser.